# Excel to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, ssis

I am loading data from Excel Source to SQL Server destination. And it is working fine.
The problem is the empty rows are also inserting into the database.

Can you help please.
Thanks

Comment: Truncate the SQL Table -> For each loop container for sheets -> Data Flow Task -> Excel Source -> Derived Column -> Data Conversion -> OLEDB Destination (SQL Server). This is what im doing. I have 4 sheets, 2 sheets are loaded perfectly, remaining two sheets loading with all the rows 1048576...

Comment: Possibly it's Excel's fault. You can have some cells which look empty by Excel still registers them as non-empty. Clean up your sheets and try again:
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteBlanks()
    Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
If still NOK, let us (the community :) know
Here's a better code for blanking empty cells: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/79575-macro-remove-blank-cells.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the step 7 of [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server---10-steps-to-follow/) he has used conditional splits you can use something like that.

Comment: I don't want to redirect any rows, I am having 147k rows as a set. But data is loading beyond this, there is no data after 147k row

Answer (score 1):

You could try introducing a Script Component into your data flow task.  Although they're based on the idea of "read a record, process it, write it", I believe you have the option of NOT writing out a particular record.  You could filter based on whether the row from Excel has content, or not.